# Gradle 7.6 'test' target is not including `src/test/resources` in classpath of Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, junit

I am working on a Spring Boot 3.0.3 app and using `@PropertySource` like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = "application-${ENV:LOCAL}.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = false)
public class SampleApp {
  // ...code
}
```

to load an alternative ENV-specific .properties file.  This works perfectly fine when the app runs, but with the unit tests I cant seem to get it to find the `application-UNIT.properties` file in `src/test/resources` or `src/main/resources`.

For example, I have this as a test:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"ENV=UNIT"})
class SampleAppTest {
  // ...code
}
```

When I run this using the mostly stock Gradle build.gradle that came with the Spring Boot Initializer at start.spring.io I get an error like:

```
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/application-UNIT.properties]
...
```

I've tried adding the path various ways, like adding it via sourceSets like:

```
sourceSets {
  test {
    resources.srcDir(file('src/test/resources'))
  }
```

Or by adding a block like:

```
test {
  classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath + files("src/test/resources")
}
```

And every combo using `${projectDir}` as a prefix, with full paths, with trailing `/`, with trailing `/*`, but nothing seems to allow the unit tests to run.  I've even put breakpoints in the `build.gradle` file and verified I see the values in the respective Gradle objects in Intelli-J's debugger.  Hoping someone can point me in the right direction here as I have exhausted my google'ing abilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I feel dumb but I finally found the answer by tracing through the Property loading code in Spring Boot.

Essentially, in the `@PropertySource` annotation on the main app class, you HAVE to start the filename with `classpath:` like:

```java
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application-${ENV:LOCAL}.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = false)
```

If you don't, it blows past the `if` block that loads the property file using the Classpath resource loader.  I still don't have an answer as to why it worked fine when I ran the app in the IDE or packaged it in a Docker container and ran it in Kubernetes, but any runs into this issue and stumbles across this post you at least have something easy to try.